# How do I visualize the implementation of an interface in a sequence diagram

Tags: java, android, uml, sequence-diagram

I want to visualize the following code in a sequence diagram.

```
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
            finish();
        }
        // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up initialization.
        mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mBluetoothLeService = null;
    }
};

protected void onCreate(){
   bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

I want to know how to visualize the overwritten Methods of the Interface ServiceConnection, since there is no actual call of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the method implementation on the sequence diagram, intependent of wheter it is invoked or not.

Just follow the code and model all the steps, as well as input parameters and return value.

In order to do it complete, model classes in class diagram, as it is often a base to the sequence modelling. Than instanciate all the objects that participate in method implementation and draw the messages between them.

Comment: ServiceConnection is an Interface from the Android SDK. How do I follow something that is invisible for me?

Comment: You cannot follow in in this case, you can only show its invocation. If there is no invocation and no specification, why would you model it in the sequence? You can then only model it in the claas diagram, it signature/declaration. That's the info you have.